# Increase the size of the "Reply To" symbol in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

I think the 'reply to' feature of the chat is very important (and good). But the 'reply to' symbol on the right side of every chat message is way to tiny, especially for tablet/mobile use.

Can we create a 'reply to' button on the right side of every message, just like the 'down arrow' field on the left side?

Comment: Often I click on it to select some text and I don't want that to accidentally be interpreted as a reply.

Comment: But you still had to actually send the message for it to become a reply.

Comment: I don't want the field populated with the message ID either... What if I then type something else, but accidentally reply to that earlier message?

Comment: What do you think of the edited idea?

Comment: Install [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/2105/se-chat-modifications-keyboard-navigation-and-commands-for-chat), use the keyboard, worry less about tiny click targets.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing me to the script Shog9, but it won't help in all cases and it's not really the solution I am looking for.